# Is there a way to create error with Fosrestbundle without using form and validation?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I mean creating an error 400, 500 generated by the ViewHandler of Fosrestbundle directly from the controller without using an Entity and a Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i understood you question correctly but there are some possibilities.

```
return $this->view(null, 400);
```

You can return the view with the status code. In some cases i thow an `HTTPException`.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

throw new HttpException(400, "Input not correct or not allowed!");
```

There you can define the status code and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line where ever you want the error

`header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);`

You may need to make sure no content has been sent prior to this error